# Web scraping site does not return correct values

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

The [site](https://www.adidas.com.sg/yeezy) I am scraping. My goal is to scrape the product ID/sku and get the link. However the elements is in the site, when i scrape the data my output will be blank/error.
current code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'}
url = "https://www.adidas.com.sg/yeezy/"
productsource = requests.get(url,headers=headers,timeout=15)
productinfo = BeautifulSoup(productsource.content, "lxml")

for item in productinfo.select('div',class_='src-components-___coming-soon__row___NfXc3'):

    sku = item.find('div', class_="src-components-___coming-soon__product___2Gai4")['id']
    link = item.a['href']
    print(sku,'\n',link)
```

Results:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\matta\OneDrive\xeonon\testing monitors\test.py", line 14, in <module>
    sku = item.find('div', class_="src-components-___coming-soon__product___2Gai4")['id']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Can anyone help? What am I doing wrong?

Update: How would I extract the 1st url

```
      "imageUrls": [
                    "https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_840,h_840,q_auto:sensitive/3d37a43625ce413ea6d3ad44013560db_9366/GZ0954_01_standard.jpg",
                    "https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_840,h_840,q_auto:sensitive/e1748ff26ad54f559ffbad4401356122_9366/GZ0954_01_standard1_hover.jpg",
                    "https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_840,h_840,q_auto:sensitive/3da89e0f71064a958377ad4401355e12_9366/GZ0954_01_standard2.jpg",
                    "https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_840,h_840,q_auto:sensitive/43136245b78840e9901bad44013561bf_9366/GZ0954_02_standard.jpg",
                    "https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_840,h_840,q_auto:sensitive/c116076d86b34098bf9cad4401355ee8_9366/GZ0954_03_standard.jpg"
                ],
```

Comment: That `find` call didn't find anything then. Double check that class names aren't ephemeral. `2Gai4` looks like a randomly generated suffix to thwart scraping.

Comment: "You may not use any software, robot, crawler, spider, page scraper or any other automated means or device to (a) access, copy, affect or monitor any part of the Website..."

Answer (score 2):

The data is embedded within the page in JavaScript. You can use this example how to parse it:

```py
import re
import json
import requests


url = "https://www.adidas.com.sg/yeezy"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0"
}

html_doc = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
data = re.search(r"window\.ENV = ({.*})", html_doc).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for id_, product in data["productData"].items():
    print(id_, product["shared"]["trackingName"], product["localized"]["color"])
    print("https://www.adidas.com.sg/yeezy/product/{}".format(id_))
```

Prints:

```
GZ0953 YEEZY SLIDE ADULTS ENFLAME ORANGE
https://www.adidas.com.sg/yeezy/product/GZ0953
GZ0954 YEEZY SLIDE KIDS ENFLAME ORANGE
https://www.adidas.com.sg/yeezy/product/GZ0954
GZ0955 YEEZY SLIDE INFANTS ENFLAME ORANGE
https://www.adidas.com.sg/yeezy/product/GZ0955
GZ5551 YEEZY SLIDE RESIN
https://www.adidas.com.sg/yeezy/product/GZ5551
GZ5554 YEEZY SLIDE PURE
https://www.adidas.com.sg/yeezy/product/GZ5554
```

Comment: hey Ive tried it and it works but 1 more questions, how would I just extract out the 1st image url from the data. I've updated my question. @Andrej Kesely

Comment: Add ```print(product["shared"]["imageUrls"][0])``` for the first image link.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0'
}


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    goal = soup.select_one('script').string.split("=", 1)[1]
    print(json.loads(goal)['productIds'])


main('https://www.adidas.com.sg/yeezy')
```

Output:

```
['GZ0953', 'GZ0954', 'GZ0955', 'GZ5551', 'GZ5554']
```